# php arrays into solr index

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I've been using mysql just to practice getting data stored. What I do is get the textnodes of an html document, its y coordinate relative to the document, and the url. I was wondering how I could do this straight into solr (since it uses xml). Some general guidance would be great as well.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($textnode); $i++) {

$textnode[$i] = stripslashes($textnode[$i]);
$textnode[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($textnode[$i], $con);



 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs, ytext, url)
 VALUES ('$textnode[$i]','$ytext[$i]', '$url')");



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take an available xml document library(there are more than one the most simple would be probably [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)) in your php script. XML Format of solr is described in their wiki([see here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#add.2BAC8-update)).

You add then your fields to the document with some names(as configured by your schema.xml). And post it to the solr interface.

See e.g. the example using curl. PHP has also a curl library. So you can implement anything there with ease.